# Is service bound before onDestory() is called?

Tags: android

I have a service bound in `onPause()` for my app to pass data like a `MediaPlayer` to the service if the app is backgrounded or closed by user. But say user closes app rather than backgrounds app. I still want data to be passed to the service, but what if `onDestory()` is called before service is bound. Is this even possible? Should I add a timer that samples `boundness` of service before allowing app to close, and give the sampling algorithm a time out? I want to be able to pass data to the service before the app is killed.

**edit**

This is what I ended up doing. I guess I'll just test it.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Create bound service with notification when app is backgrounded or killed
    // and pass media player to bound service so user can control media player
    // from notification.

    bindMediaPlayerService();

    // It might be possible that if the user closes the app that the service will not be bound
    // before onDestroy() is called. After onPause() is called, the app should no longer be
    // visible, so it should be okay to add a waiter here in the form of a sampler which
    // samples the boundedness of the service for N seconds before timing out.

    sampleBoundednessOfServiceUntilTimeOut(5);
}

private void sampleBoundednessOfServiceUntilTimeOut(int timeOutSec)
{
    Log.d(TAG,"sampleBoundednessOfServiceUntilTimeOut() timeOutSec="+timeOutSec);
    long startSec = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(true)
    {
        if(mBound)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"service bound in time, no time out required");
            break;
        }
        long endSec = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(endSec - startSec > timeOutSec)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"service did not bind in time, timing out");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a service bound in onPause() what do you mean by that? You meant unbind(...); ?

Comment: Shoudnt you be calling bindMediaPlayerService(); in onResume() ?

Comment: @RohitSingh Not necessarily. I only want the service and the notification to exist when the app is not in the foreground so the user can only see the notification with the media player controls when the app is not in the foreground, but not when the app is in the foreground.

Comment: And then the app and the service will exchange the media player with each other. On the other hand, I could keep the service alive at all time and just embed the media player into the service.

Comment: But then the problem I think is the notification will always be visible and I will have the service running when I don't really need it.

Comment: I guess what I can do is just start the service in onResume as you say, and make the notification visible in onPause. I guess having MediaPlayer in a service at all times isn't bad.

Comment: And also make the notification not visible in onResume

Comment: Then there is no point of binding a service to Activity. Binding should be done within the scope of Activitie/s . else use a startService() method. Do you understand the difference between bindService() and startService() ?

Comment: I guess what I can do is just star...... Thats right.